# Filling list with input arrays

Tags: arrays, list, object, groovy, each

I've got a problem with lists in groovy, I have the following inputs to my script

[image: Script inputs]

My requirement is to put my inputs into a list like the following example provided by a user here:

```
final int OID = 0
final int TASK = 1
final int START = 2
final int END = 3
final int REALSTART = 4
final int REALEND = 5

List<Object[]> input = [
        [ 'oid', 'task', 10, 20, 11, 25 ],
        [ 'oid2', 'task2', 25, 50, null, null ]
]


List<List> output = [ ]

input.each { row ->
    output << [ row[ OID ], row[ TASK ], row[ START ], row[ END ] ]
    if ( row[ REALSTART ] && row[ REALEND ] ) {
        output << [ row[ OID ], row[ TASK ] + '_Real', row[ REALSTART ], row[ REALEND ] ]
    }
}
```

My problem is the input list part, I can't figure how to fill it like the example so that my input list result is:

```
[oid1,task1,start1,end1,realstart1,realend1]
[oid2,task2,start2,end2,realstart2,realend2]
[oid3,task3,start3,end3,realstart3,realend3]
[oid4,task4,start4,end4,realstart4,realend4]
[oid5,task5,start5,end5,realstart5,realend5]
```

with my given input values. `timeNow` is irrelevant in this case.

Is it clear enough?

Comment: _"Is it clear enough?"_ Not really, no.  What do you have (example input), what do you require (example output), what have you tried, and what problems have you hit?

Comment: ok you want to restructure your input into ```[oid1,task1,start1,end1,realstart1,realend1]``` format but what does it look like intially?

Comment: initially is like: `List<int> oid, List<String> task, List<Timestamp> start` and so on. So it's a list for each attribute. Imagine those are arrays, i need to have my output like: `{ oid[0],task[0],start[0]...}{ oid[1],task[1],start[1]..} ..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine each nth element of a list of lists, groovy has the `transpose` function:

```
[["oid1","oid2","oid3","oid4","oid5"],
 ["task1","task2","task3","task4","task5"],
 ["start1","start2","start3","start4","start5"],
 ["end1","end2","end3","end4","end5"],
 ["realstart11","realstart12","realstart13","realstart14","realstart15"],
 ["realend11","realend12","realend13","realend14","realend15"],].transpose()

// [[oid1, task1, start1, end1, realstart11, realend11], [oid2, task2, start2, end2, realstart12, realend12], [oid3, task3, start3, end3, realstart13, realend13], [oid4, task4, start4, end4, realstart14, realend14], [oid5, task5, start5, end5, realstart15, realend15]]
```

Comment: interesting did not know that method :)

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this.
**Input** (per your comment):

```
def oids = ["oid1","oid2","oid3","oid4","oid5"];
def tasks = ["task1","task2","task3","task4","task5"];
def starts = ["start1","start2","start3","start4","start5"];
def ends = ["end1","end2","end3","end4","end5"];
def realstart1s = ["realstart11","realstart12","realstart13","realstart14","realstart15"];
def realend1s = ["realend11","realend12","realend13","realend14","realend15"];
```

**Algorithm**:

```
def result = [];

oids.size().times{
    result << [oids[it], tasks[it], starts[it], ends[it], realstart1s[it], realend1s[it]]
}
```

**Output**:

```
[
[oid1, task1, start1, end1, realstart11, realend11],
[oid2, task2, start2, end2, realstart12, realend12],
[oid3, task3, start3, end3, realstart13, realend13], 
[oid4, task4, start4, end4, realstart14, realend14], 
[oid5, task5, start5, end5, realstart15, realend15]
]
```